# What is wrong with my sql query of odata?

Tags: sql, database, sql-order-by, odata

I am trying to get the number of users for each age.
What is wrong with this sql query for odata.stackoverflow.com?

```
select age, count(*) 
from users 
order by age 
group by age
```

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: I thought I did.  I posted the question like 8 times but encountered a bug that prevented me from posting it so maybe on the 9th time I did not format it correctly.  Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
  select age,count(*) 
    from users 
group by age 
order by age
```

ORDER BY is always last

Comment: Thanks so much.  I have ran into this problem several times over the past few years and always used a simple work around instead of digging into it.